# utility to view qemu virtualized hardware

Tags: qemu

I have one `qemu` VM running in my PC:

```
# cat -A /proc/$(pgrep qemu)/cmdline | sed 's/\^@/ /g'; echo
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -no-user-config -daemonize -cpu Haswell -smp 2,cores=2 -m 4G -device qxl-vga -device e1000,netdev=network,mac=52:54:00:b4:00:43 -netdev tap,id=network,ifname=tap1,script=no,downscript=no -drive file=/home/diskimg,if=virtio -display vnc=:1
#
```

While the command itself gives some insight of the VM, then is there a CLI utility to view the details and all the automatically created devices(I haven't specified `-nodefaults`)? Or is the only possibility to view this information from guest?

Comment: If your VM has an IP address and is running an ssh daemon, you can always run commands like `ssh vm-name-or-ip lspci` from the qemu host system.  Alternatively (or additionally) you could also use a serial console on your VM, or just have a serial port running a `getty`.

Answer (score 2):

There is `virsh` which has a subcommand `dumpxml` which will show you all the information you seek. If there is a pretty printing version, I don't know. There are quite a few subcommands with documentation though.

So first you list all your VMs

```
virsh list
```

Every VM has an ID, e.g. 16. You can then look at the specifics using

```
virsh dumpxml 16
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand, `virsh` requires `libvirt` library being able to connect to an already running `libvirtd` service. My `qemu` VM was not created using `libvirt`.

Comment: @Martin: It doesn't matter how your VM was createded, but it's true, that libvirtd must be running and that your hypervisor must be managed/manageable through it so that `virsh` can be used.